# Angular 5 ngFor Array generated by Input Setter, not updating

Tags: angular

I am making a HotelRating component that should show how many stars a hotel have out of a max. (Eg. 3 og 5 stars)

Both the max and the current rating should be inputs form the parent component.

Currently I get the values form the parent and generates an boolean array, so that I can use an *ngFor to make the stars in the template.

My problem is that the ngFor is not updated when generate the array in my @Input Setter function.

My code is below. 
Hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong, or maybe have a better solution to solve my assignment.

TS:

```
export class HotelStarsComponent {
  // An array to hold the values for the rating component
  ratingArray:boolean[] = [];
  // Input containing the max number of stars available
  @Input() maxRating:number = 5;
  // Internal variable to store the hotel rating
  private _hotelRating;
  // The setter sets to value of the "internal" variable to the input value
  @Input() set hotelRating(hotelRating: number) {
    this._hotelRating = hotelRating;
    for(let i = 0; i < this.maxRating; i++){
      this.ratingArray.push(i < hotelRating ? true : false);
    }
  }
  // The getter is used to get the variable
  get hotelRating() {
    return this._hotelRating;
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<span 
  class="star" 
  uk-icon="icon: github-alt; ratio: .75"
  *ngFor="let star of ratingArray"
  [class.active]="star">
</span>
```

Comment: Maybe it can help: [trackBy](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngfor-with-trackby)

Comment: and if you throw a console log in the set hotelRating, does it print every time the parent passes through new ratings?

Comment: [ngClass]="{'active':star}">

Comment: @Everett Yes, If I console.log the ratingArray it shows the correct array.

Comment: @Eliseo This does not make any difference. It never even generates the objects after the input is changed

Comment: @Efe I will take a look!

Comment: I hope it will resolve your issue!

Comment: You should clear your ratingArray inside the setter before pushing new boolean in it